# Opening a window in javascript (window.open) on rollover without getting blocked by popup blockers

Tags: javascript, events, click, rollover, window.open

I like to open a new window (not in the same window) in JavaScript with window.open on rollover (without click event) and it gets blocked by popup blocker in IE and Firefox. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: The answer is, don't do it. It annoys the heck out of your users. It's evil and immoral. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way around it. You can't force browsers to do something they're not willing to do (by overt design!), and if you were to figure out a way it'd be treated like a severe bug and fixed as soon as possible.

Firefox can be reconfigured (by its user, not by a page or its code) to change the list of events that it considers "safe" for window opening, I think.

Comment: can you answer this question of mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232546/browser-window-popups-risks-and-special-features ?

Answer (score 3):

No, most browsers will explicitly block this action by design.  The idea is that users would not expect a legitimate popup to be generated by anything other than a mouse click.